# Asmx WebService - WSDL differs on DEBUG and RELEASE configuration

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have the ASMX WebService (let's call it "A"), which is connected to 2 more webServices ("B" and "C"). The problem is,  when I start WebService "A" on my local machine (using VS Development Server) on DEBUG configuration, the resulting wsdl:definitions node in the WSDL is like that (simplified and ordered):

```
<wsdl:definitions
...
xmlns:s1="B"
xmlns:s2="C"
xmlns:s3="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"
.../>
```

And when I start the same service on the same local machine (using the same VS Development Server) on RELEASE config, it becomes this:

```
<wsdl:definitions
...
xmlns:s1="C"
xmlns:s2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"
xmlns:s3="B"
.../>
```

It's not the big problem by itself, but it gets harder to analyze my WSDL when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that checking the "Optimize code" flag on Debug fixes that problem. Still don't know what is the root of the problem though